# Do Manifested or Morphed creatures count as tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

Does a manifested creature or even a morph creature count as a token? I was told yes, but I was also told that a card can never be considered a token! So I'm asking you guys!

Comment: A card is never a token. *110.5. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield. A token is a marker used to represent any permanent that isn’t represented by a card.*

Answer (score 9):

No.

Both the morph and manifest abilities that allow you to have a face-down permanent apply only to cards (morph works on creature cards in your hand, and manifest on cards from your library). The other two ways to have face-down permanents ([Illusionary Mask](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusionary%20Mask) and [Ixidron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ixidron)) apply either to creature cards or nontoken creatures.

If some effect (e.g., [Fated Infatuation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fated%20Infatuation)) makes a token copy of a face-down creature, it will simply be a 2/2 creature with no text, name, type, nor mana cost. It cannot be turned "face up" because being "face down" is NOT a copiable characteristic. Therefore the token is not actually "face down".

Comment: Thx people's!  I knew they weren't tokens! But  people out numbered me on the subject!

Comment: The confusion is likely due to the morph and manifest indicator "cards" in KTK and FRF packs that are similar to the token "cards" that are also found in packs. I'm curious about what these people think happens when you bounce a morph - since a token that leaves the battlefield ceases to exist.